# Permission denied while binding socket

Tags: python, linux, sockets

It's me again from [Running Python server forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440269/running-python-server-forever/12441458). I *did* upload my file to the server, but I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./application", line 42, in <module>
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

For your reference, the code is here:

```
...

TCP_IP = ''
TCP_PORT = 9090
BUFFER_SIZE = 256

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    ClientThread(conn, addr).start()
```

When the socket binds to port 9090, (or any other port for that matter), it just returns this exception. I don't need to be `root`, because `port > 1024`.

What should I change? Is the problem in TCP_IP or TCP_PORT?

~Chance

Comment: But does it work if you're root?

Comment: I don't know. I can't login as root. `bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied`

Comment: are the permissions on `/usr/bin/sudo` right? has `sudo` ever worked? is this your machine?

Comment: I'm doing this on an EC2 server which is, of course, not mine. The server and client work well on my machine.

Comment: This is relevant! I wonder if it is an EC2 limitation, but I know very little about EC2.

Comment: It's more likely to do with the IP.. As you mentioned the port is above 1024 so I don't know how it can become a problem. Can you try `127.0.0.1` for IP?

Comment: Binding to the wrong or invalid IP address should give Errno 99 "Cannot assign requested address"

Comment: @KayZhu The server works _completely_ fine on my computer. It only spits out that error when on the EC2, _even using `127.0.0.1`_.

Answer (score 1):

try using `'0.0.0.0`' as the bind address. In Linux, this means all interfaces.

```
TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
```

And make sure SELinux is disabled.

Comment: If your distro uses SELinux, you can check its status with the command `getenforce`. What does the command return?

Comment: `Enforcing` Does that mean I can't run it on this server?

Comment: Edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and set it to disabled.  Reboot and try again.

Comment: Should I have said first that I use _RedHat OpenShift_? I think they don't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Set the host to "None" such that it binds properly to all adapter interfaces.

```
host = None
s.bind((host, TCP_PORT));
```

Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html

Comment: damn!. I might have gotten my code from a different doc. But then I get this: `TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found` What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest isolating the problem further, meaning you want to reproduce this problem using something that "should also work" but is not your code.

For example, try a canned (known-working) HTTP script server, and observe that if it also fails then the issue is nothing to do with the Python code you posted. This will get you on the right track... permissions.

FYI - On EC2 I don't think you log in as root -- MY EC2 doesn't support root (it's Ubuntu). Instead you "sudo" run the command, while logged in as you. I'm not prompted for a sudo password (although someone may have configured that before me, by adding NOPASSWORD=ALL to my /etc/sudoers user or group).

What I know about EC2 is you have a firewall and permissions BOTH on the OS itself, and in the Amazon EC2 control panel, and you can easily run into permissions issue and waste time looking in the wrong place.

Anyways, confirm that it's permissions not your Python code, and then take this problem to an EC2 forum for best results.